# Probability that number of heads flipped is divisible by 3

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

### You toss a coin n times. What is the probability that the number of heads you’ll get is divisible by 3?

(Find an exact formula, not involving sums of unbounded length; it may depend on
the remainder of n modulo 6).

I believe that the problem is to find a formula for:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} {n \choose 3i}}{2^n}$$ but I'm not really sure how to find a formula for the sum in the numerator. A hint for how to evaluate $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n/3} {n \choose 3i}$$ when n is divisible by three would also be much appreciated

(**Note**: this is not a homework problem)

Comment: If this is not homework, please let us know and I will post a complete answer.  For now, I give you this hint:  There is a nifty way to do this with transforms.  If this is homework, this may not be the answer your instructor was expecting.

Comment: Multiplicate, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/371566/6179) for example.

Comment: Shameless [ad](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6179++discrete+Fourier+transform).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\omega $ be a primitive cube root of unit.

**Hint:** Consider $(1 + \omega)^n, ( 1 + \omega^2)^n, (1+1)^n$. Expand using the Binomial Theorem, and use the fact that $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0, \omega^3 = 1 $.

This shows that $(1 + \omega)^n+ ( 1 + \omega^2)^n+ (1+1)^n = 3 \sum { n \choose 3i} $.

Comment: The approach is similar to the hint I had in mind.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn Yes, the discrete Fourier transform :)

Comment: Thanks this was a very clever and quick response!! In general is it true that $$\sum\limits_{k \ge 0} {n \choose rk} = \frac{1}{r} \sum \limits_{j = 1}^r {(1 + \omega^j)^n}$$ What was the motivation to bring roots of unity?

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Are you saying the answer is $\frac{ 2^n - (-1)^n}{3 \cdot 2^n}$?  This is incorrect for  $n = 3$, for example.  Empirically, it seems to be true if $n$ is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Yes if n is a multiple of 3 then $$\omega^n + \omega^{2n} = 2$$ Therefore the sum can be handled according to cases n mod 6

Answer (score 3):

Theorem:  Let  $X$ be an integer-valued random variable.  $P\{n \text{ divides } X\}=\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n \phi(2\pi k/n)$, where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$.  In words, this probability is the average of the probability generating function evaluated at the $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity.

I published this result in the 90's, but the proof is short.  Here is an even more compact version.  Let $W = \text{exp}(i\frac{2\pi X}n)$. Then $\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n W^k = 1$if  $n$ divides $X$, 0 otherwise.  Hence, its expectation is the probability of the event.  Apply linearity.

In your case, $X$ ~ Binomial($n$, 1/2).  $\phi(t)=[(1+e^{it})/2]^n$.  Eventually, we get the desired probability to be $\frac13(1+2\text{ Re }e^{i\pi n/3}/2^n)$.

Final answer to your problem:  $\frac13(1+c_{n\text{ mod }6}2^{-n})$, where  $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5)= (2,1,-1,-2,-1,1)$.

Comment: Do you know about characteristic functions?

Comment: Sorry not really. I am not really familiar with much of probability theory.

Comment: $\phi(t)=Ee^{itX}$.  In the case of discrete random variables, this becomes $\sum_x e^{itx} \ P\{X=x\}$.  Thus, if $X$ ~ Bernoulli($p$), $\phi(t)=1-p+pe^{it}$.  The characteristic function of a sum of independent random variables is the product of the c.f.'s.  Thus, the c.f. of a Binomial($n, p$) r.v. is $(1-p+pe^{it})^n$.

Comment: Nice. Except the sum should be from k=0 to n-1.

Comment: Valentas, you are correct.